# Facebook Comments Moderation Tool is not showing new comments as pending approval

Tags: facebook

My Facebook Comments Moderation Tool is not showing new comments as pending approval and makes all comments public while in my settings it's set to let me approve every comment.

This bug has just appeared recently, but I never made any changes to the settings.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction to get this bug fixed and bring back comment moderation.

The moderation link is no longer visible: I just switch to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/ to see previous comments, but new comments are not visible there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your URL Open Graph meta tags via the debug tool, to see if it reads all the values ok.

Comment: Thanks! It says:     
"Share App ID Missing
The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog."

Is this some kind of a new requirement from Facebook?

Comment: What about the meta tags relevant to comment moderation?

Comment: The empty tags are: fb:app_id and op:markup_url

Comment: Can you give an actual example URL?

Answer (score 0):

We have found that the reason of this bug was related to Facebook cache.